# Adjacency matrix for weighted DAG with multiple connections between same nodes

Tags: python, ruby, algorithm, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

My graph is,

```
v1 v2 t1 t2
1   2 15 20 
1   3  1 6 
2   4 25 30 
3   4  2 7  
3   4 30 35
```

where t1 and t2 are departure time and time it takes to go from v1 to v2
Starting at time 0 and vertex 1 always while end vertex 4, in this example min dist is 30. We could also reach 4 from 3 but can't really arrive 3 before 2 hence 1-2-4 is the path.
There cannot be an edge between two nodes if t1 of v2 is not less than t2 of v1.
Imagine a bus travel route, you can't catch a bus if it leaves before you arrive.
Using python i'm making graph as

```
graph = {'1':{'2':[15,20], '3':[1,6]}, '2':{'4':[25,30]}, '3':{'4':([2,7],[30,35])}}
```

If I were to make an adjacency matrix how would I go about it since there are two edges possible from V(3) to V(4) namely (2,7) and (30,35).
Ultimate goal is to find the minimum amount of time it'll take to go from one station to another.
Also if there is any other way apart from Dijkstra since I tried it and not able to solve the problem of multiple connections from same node there is no way to find out which edge was it according to the graph i make.

Comment: do you start at time 0 at  certain vertex? do you have only two time stamps?

Comment: yea I start at time 0 and vertex 1 always and end vertex is 4, in this example min dist is 30. We could also reach 4 from 3 but can't really arrive 3 before 2 hence 1-2-4 is the path.

Comment: what `t1 ` and `t2` are suppose to designate? the time when the bus arrives/leaves?

Comment: where t1 is departure time and t2 is time it takes to go from v1 to v2 @svs

Comment: Dijkstra should solve your problem. `I tried it and not able to solve the problem of multiple connections from same node there is no way to find out which edge was it according to the graph i make`. After an update you should just save which is the parent of the updated node.